# Cómo usar i18n en un controller si se se ha instanciado en app.js usando express en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, i18n

Instancio i18n en app.js así:

```
const i18n = require("i18n");
i18n.configure({
  locales:['en','es'],
  defaultLocale: 'es',
  register: global,
  header: 'accept-language', //HEADER QUE CONFIGURA EL LENGUAJE
  directory: path.resolve("./") + '\\locales',
  queryParameter: 'lang'
});

app.use(i18n.init);
```

y lo uso y funciona normalmente en un controller, llega la petición auth.routes.js se la pasa al controller auth.controller, dónde lo instancio así:

```
const i18n = require("i18n");
```

y uso así:

```
i18n.__(....)
```

pero cuando la ruta es así: petición llega a auth.routes.js la paso a hacer una validación a users.controller.js no funciona, instanciándolo y usándolo de la misma manera.

así:

en auth.routes.js

```
router.post("/singin", [userCtrl.validate("singIn")], authController.singIn);
```

en users.controller.js

```
const i18n = require("i18n");
export const validate = async(method) => {
  return body("email").trim().not().isEmpty().withMessage( i18n.__('RESPONSES')['MSGS_VALIDATIONS']['NOT_EMPTY'])
}
```

el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> .....i18n.js:1378
> logWarnFn(msg)
>
> TypeError: logWarnFn is not a function